Error while building Linux kernel 5.4 on Kali Linux
Problem with building kernel on Realme Note 50.
Can anyone help?
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:43:17: error: static assertion failed: "include/linux/sched.h:1312: struct{ u64 last_enqueue_ts; u64 last_sleep_ts; } is larger than "
43 | _Static_assert(sizeof(struct{_new;}) <= sizeof(struct{_orig;}),
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:67:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘__ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN’
67 | __ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN(_orig, _new);
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/sched.h:1312:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE’
1312 | _ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE(ANDROID_VENDOR_DATA_ARRAY(1, 2), struct{ u64 last_enqueue_ts; u64 last_sleep_ts; });
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:48:17: error: static assertion failed: “include/linux/sched.h:1312: is not aligned the same as struct{ u64 last_enqueue_ts; u64 last_sleep_ts; }”
48 | _Static_assert(alignof(struct{_new;}) <= alignof(struct{_orig;}),
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:67:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘__ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN’
67 | __ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN(_orig, _new);
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/sched.h:1312:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE’
1312 | _ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE(ANDROID_VENDOR_DATA_ARRAY(1, 2), struct{ u64 last_enqueue_ts; u64 last_sleep_ts; });
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:43:17: error: static assertion failed: "include/linux/sched.h:1314: struct{ unsigned long last_switch_count; unsigned long last_switch_time; unsigned long used_for_hung_task; } is larger than "
43 | _Static_assert(sizeof(struct{_new;}) <= sizeof(struct{_orig;}),
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:67:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘__ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN’
67 | __ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN(_orig, _new);
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/sched.h:1314:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE’
1314 | _ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE(ANDROID_OEM_DATA_ARRAY(1, 3), struct{ unsigned long last_switch_count; unsigned long last_switch_time; unsigned long used_for_hung_task; });
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:48:17: error: static assertion failed: “include/linux/sched.h:1314: is not aligned the same as struct{ unsigned long last_switch_count; unsigned long last_switch_time; unsigned long used_for_hung_task; }”
48 | _Static_assert(alignof(struct{_new;}) <= alignof(struct{_orig;}),
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/android_kabi.h:67:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘__ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN’
67 | __ANDROID_KABI_CHECK_SIZE_ALIGN(_orig, _new);
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/sched.h:1314:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE’
1314 | _ANDROID_KABI_REPLACE(ANDROID_OEM_DATA_ARRAY(1, 3), struct{ unsigned long last_switch_count; unsigned long last_switch_time; unsigned long used_for_hung_task; });
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:104: arch/arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.s] error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1243: prepare0] error 2```


How is this related to Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

I don't know, I use Kali, I thought maybe they could help here

See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me
